# Exclude rows where keys match, but are on different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm looking for the best way to produce the result set in the scenario provided. My cust3 column isn't identifying the repeated values in the indvid2 column. The end result I'm looking for is to exclude the rows where key1 and key2 match (ids:1,2,6 and 7), then sum accounts where the acctids match.If there's a better way to code this, I welcome all suggestions. Thanks!

```
WITH T10 as (
SELECT acctid,invid,(
case
when invid like '%-R' then left (InvID,LEN(invid) -2) else InvID
     END) as InvID2
FROM table x 
    GROUP BY acctID,invID 
    ),


T11 as (
SELECT acctid, Invid2, COUNT(InvID2) as cust3
FROM T10
    GROUP BY InvID2,acctid
    HAVING 
    COUNT (InvID2) > 1
    )

select DISTINCT
a.acctid,
a.name,
b.invid,
C.invid2,
D.cust3,
b.amt,
b.key1,
b.key2

from table a
inner join table b (nolock) on a.acctid = b.acctid
inner join T10 C (nolock) on b.invid = c.invid
inner join T11 D (nolock) on C.invid2 = D.invid2
```

Resultset

```
id  acctID  name    invid   invid2  Cust3   amt     key1    key2
1   123    James    101      101    2      $500     NULL    6789
2   123    james    101-R    101    2     ($500)    6789    NULL
3   123    James    102      102    2      $350     NULL    NULL
4   123    James    103      103    2      $200     NULL    NULL
5   246     Tony    98-R      98    2     ($750)    7423    NULL
6   432    David    45        45    2      $100     NULL    9634
7   432    David    45-R      45    2     ($100)    9634    NULL
8   359     Stan    39-R      39    2      ($50)    6157    NULL
9   753   George    95        95    2      $365     NULL    NULL
10  753   George    108      108    2      $100     NULL    NULL
```

Desired Resultset

```
id  acctID  name    invid   invid2  Cust3   amt     key1    key2
1   123    James    101      101    2      $500     NULL    6789
2   123    james    101-R    101    2     ($500)    6789    NULL
3   123    James    102      102    1      $350     NULL    NULL
4   123    James    103      103    1      $200     NULL    NULL
5   246     Tony    98-R      98    1     ($750)    7423    NULL
6   432    David    45        45    2      $100     NULL    9634
7   432    David    45-R      45    2     ($100)    9634    NULL
8   359     Stan    39-R      39    1      ($50)    6157    NULL
9   753    George   95        95    1      $365     NULL    NULL
10  753    George   108      108    1      $100     NULL    NULL
```

Then to sum amt by acctid

```
id  acctid  name    amt                 
1   123    James    $550                    
2   246     Tony    ($750)                  
3   359     Stan    ($50)                   
4   753    George   $465
```

Comment: Unclear.  You say you want to 1,2,6,& 7, but they are in your desired result set.   And then you want to sum?   So are you looking for a stored procedure that returns two result sets?

Comment: so in the desired result set the Cust3 column identifies the line items that I want to exclude. Which I can do in my "Where" clause... something like, where cust3 <> '2', and then remove the invid, invid2, cust3, and Key columns, then sum the "Amt" column where the acctID match... Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
;WITH Keys as (
    SELECT Key1.acctID, [Key] = Key1.Key1
    FROM YourTable as Key1
    INNER JOIN YourTable as Key2
        ON Key1.Key1 = Key2.Key2 and Key1.acctID = Key2.acctID
)
SELECT t.acctID, t.name, amt = SUM(t.amt)
FROM YourTable as t
LEFT JOIN Keys as k
    ON t.acctID = k.acctID and (t.Key1 = [Key] or t.Key2 = [Key])
WHERE k.acctID is Null
GROUP BY t.acctID, t.name
```